# Solving a fourth order differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I want to solve this differential equation $$  u^{(4)}+a u^{(2)} +bu=0$$

I put $v=u^{(2)}.$ I obtain the new equation $v^{(2)}+a v+bu=0.$

What to do with $u?$ How to continue?

Thanks!

Comment: Are $a$ and $b$ constants?

Comment: yes @adrian keister

Comment: @complexmanifold: The notation $u^{(2)}$ means the second derivative of $u,$ not the square of $u.$

Comment: @complexmanufold $u^{(2)}$ means the second derivative of u

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't do the substitution then, because it's unclear how to "not do" an operation like differentiation. I would go from the original DE, and substitute in the usual ansatz: $u=e^{\lambda x}$ (assuming $u=u(x).$) Then we obtain the quartic equation $\lambda^4+a\lambda^2+b=0.$ Here's where we would do the substitution $\alpha=\lambda^2,$ to obtain the quadratic $\alpha^2+a\alpha+b=0.$ The solution here is
$$\alpha=\frac{-a\pm\sqrt{a^2-4b}}{2}. $$
We could get negative roots, making pairs of $\lambda$'s complex conjugates. We have
$$\lambda=\pm\sqrt{\frac{-a\pm\sqrt{a^2-4b}}{2}}. $$
So the solution would be
\begin{align*}
u(x)=
&A\exp\left(x\sqrt{\frac{-a+\sqrt{a^2-4b}}{2}}\right)+
B\exp\left(x\sqrt{\frac{-a-\sqrt{a^2-4b}}{2}}\right)+\\
&C\exp\left(-x\sqrt{\frac{-a+\sqrt{a^2-4b}}{2}}\right)+
D\exp\left(-x\sqrt{\frac{-a-\sqrt{a^2-4b}}{2}}\right) .
\end{align*}
You would need initial conditions to find $A, B, C,$ and $D.$ If there are complex solutions, you can translate to sine and cosine if you wish via
$$e^{i\theta}=\cos(\theta)+i\sin(\theta). $$

Comment: thank you is there a methods  when a and b are functions?

Comment: @Vrouvrou Not in general.

Comment: That's way harder! It would depend on the functions. Most often, if you need an analytical solution, series solutions are your only option.

Comment: "We're definitely going to get at least one negative root" Not if $a<0<b$.

Comment: J.G. You're right, thanks! I'll edit.

Comment: please is there a document which give methods to résolve 4order chère a  and b are function

Comment: @Vrouvrou: It's just the standard series solution method available in any sophomore-level differential equations textbook. You can look at Boyce and DiPrima, or Zill for a reference.

Comment: please I have this bvp $y""+3y"+2y=0, y(0)=y(\infty)=0, y"(0)=y"(\infty)=0$ I found only the trivial solution is it true? @Adrian Keister

Answer (score 1):

Сharacteristic equation $t^4+at^2+b=0$. Then $t_{1,2,3,4}=\pm \sqrt{\frac{-a \pm \sqrt{a^2-4b}}{2}}$. Then $u=C_1e^{t_1x}+C_2e^{t_2x}+C_3e^{t_3x}+C_4e^{t_4x}$.

Comment: but $-a-\sqrt{a^2-4b}$ is negative ????

Comment: If $a<0$ then positive. If $t_i$ is complex then there is Euler's formula.

Comment: what is euler formula?

Comment: Your problem is quite standard. Solution methods are described in textbooks ( http://www.math.psu.edu/tseng/class/Math251/Notes-HigherOrderLinEq.pdf ).

Answer (score 1):

According to your idea the formulation is

$$
\begin{cases}
u'' = v\\
v''=-a v-b u
\end{cases}
$$

You can now follow with the Laplace transform obtaining

$$
\begin{cases}
s^2U(s) - su'(0)-u(0) = V(s)\\
s^2V(s)-s v'(0) - v(0) = -a V(s) - b U(s)
\end{cases}
$$

etc.

Comment: and if a and b are functions de can use this methods?

Comment: @Vrouvrou  With $a(t),b(t)$ is not straightforward.

Comment: i don't understand what you mean?

Comment: @Vrouvrou For instance, if $a(t) = t^n$ the Laplace transform gives another differential equation now in $s$. For $a(t), b(t)$ Laplace transformable functions, after transforming we get an integral (convolutional) equation. Those diffrential or integral or integrodiffrential equations in $s$ can be quite cumbersome to solve.